# error failed to lookup view

Tags: nodejs, express, views, handlebars.js

Actualmente estoy iniciando con mi aprendizaje con NodeJS y express.

Mi problema surgue con una ruta que me manda un error, en este caso con la ruta de usuario

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/users/signin', (reg, res) =>{
    res.render('/users/signin');
});

router.get('/users/snngup', (reg, res) =>{
    res.render('/users/signup');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Esas rutas en especifico me mandan el error el cual tiene el titulo, la herramientas que estoy usando es express-handlebars.

En seguida muestro mi configuracion de motor de vistas.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exhbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Mis rutas:

```
app.use(require('./routes/index'));
app.use(require('./routes/notes'));
app.use(require('./routes/users'));
```

El error completo que me manda

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "/users/signin" in views directory 

    "C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\src\views"
        at Function.render (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
        at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
        at router.get (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\src\routes\users.js:4:9)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at next (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
        at Function.process_params (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
        at next (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
        at Function.handle (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
        at router (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
        at C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
        at Function.process_params (C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Node\TEST\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

Enseguida muestro la estructura de mis carpetas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por su atencion.

Comment: pudiste encontrar la solución? Tengo el mismo inconveniente. Saludos

Comment: Si lo resolví, al momento de querer cargar las rutas lo hacía con '/users/signin' osea que estaba apuntando a una ruta que no existe y me daba error de lookup, ya corregí la ruta a 'users/signin' y listo, la ruta correcta y sin el error